# angularui datepicker: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'show-weeks' in undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use a simple popup datepicker with angularui like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJvB2VYrlIjWMp0BXXIo?p=preview).
When I'm copying the markup and the javascript code to my app I'm getting this:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'show-weeks' in undefined
    at link (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js:1247:43)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6220:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5630:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6214:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5630:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13) <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"> angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:6832
nodeLinkFn angular.js:6223
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5630
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5633
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5633
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5633
nodeLinkFn angular.js:6214
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5630
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5633
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5633
publicLinkFn angular.js:5535
(anonymous function) angular.js:1303
Scope.$eval angular.js:11949
Scope.$apply angular.js:12049
(anonymous function) angular.js:1301
invoke angular.js:3704
doBootstrap angular.js:1299
bootstrap angular.js:1313
angularInit angular.js:1262
(anonymous function) angular.js:20549
trigger angular.js:2341
(anonymous function) angular.js:2612
forEach angular.js:309
eventHandler
```

I can post the code of my app, but it basically goes like:

```
angular.module('appName', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function MyCtrl($scope, $http) { 
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
    };

  // ... the rest of the code EXACTLY like in the plnkr

  });

  <html ng-app="appName">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
               is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
               date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </html>
```

I'm also using the SAME angularjs/angularui/bootstrap CDN as appears in the plnkr. WHY does it happen in my app while in the plnkr it works just fine?!

EDIT:

After not getting any answers I decided to change angularui's source code around line 1247 where the exception rises. I'm not the best javascript programmer in the world, so I just made sure that `datepickerOptions` is an object before using the operator `in` on it:

```
if (!((typeof(datepickerOptions) === "object")) || !('show-weeks' in datepickerOptions)) {
  scope.showWeeks = datepickerConfig.showWeeks;
} else {
  scope.showWeeks = datepickerOptions['show-weeks'];
}
```

I'm still looking for a real solution though.

Comment: I would avoid editing the source until you're sure you know what it's doing.  Maybe not even then.  ;)

Comment: @blurd +1 Post that as an answer. If there really is a problem with the Angular code, why only fix it for himself? Share it with the Angular them & if it really is a problem then they will fix it for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `datepicker-options="dateOptions"`

### Explanation

You can see in [the Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) under  **Popup Settings**

> Options for datepicker can be passed as JSON using the datepicker-options attribute.

The example you copied uses `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` in the directive.  The error is telling you Angular is trying to find the `show-weeks` value set in `dateOptions`.  The problem is, `dateOptions` is not defined in the html.

Look at the JavaScript in the example, and you'll see the missing variable is defined in the controller's scope.

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
  'year-format': "'yy'",
  'starting-day': 1
};
```

Comment: Awesome. How can you answer this question?